# How to prevent DHCP server from behind the router to answer to DHCP requests?

Tags: freebsd, routing, dhcp, pfsense

I found, that sometimes DHCP server from behind my main router answers DHCP request from clients in the `LAN`. Below is an example

[image]

Notebook is connected to `LAN` via access point. There is DHCP server running on `LAN` at `pfSense`. There is also `DHCP` server running on `Router3`. Sometimes, notebook receives address from `Router3`.

The question is: how it can be and how to patch this bleach?

In my firewall I have a rule `192.168.100.0/24` to pass so that I could open router web GUI from any clients. But I don't want it's DHCP server serves...

**UPDATE 1**

Probably I was wrongly blaming `Router3` device. I found another device that could provide `DHCP` services: I have also multimedia player with built-in `AP` functionality. I have turned it on some time ago, but it didn't worked as I expected, so I forgot about it. Although it has `192.168.100.1` undocumented `DHCP` server inside. I deduced this by `MAC` address of that fake `DHCP` server, which has first bytes the same as of this device. Now I turned `AP` off and will see how it will behave.

Comment: Indeed, you'll need to either enable NAT routing on the pfSense system, or use the upstream DHCP server `Router3`

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro how does second router hears broadcast requests? Why do they pass trhough pfsense?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I want `pfSense` do DHCP for LAN and any other servers do their DHCP in their subnets, not around the entire globe!

Comment: okok, a Internet label would have helped. I think I am understanding it better now. Either you configured a DHCP relay in pfsense, or there are some cables in the wrong sockets, or you configured a bridge. Or you used a single NIC instead of two NICs in pfsense...or ultimately, your notebook has a static IP address. Giving the benefit of doubt, I would go for the DHCP relay possibility.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro nothing applied except DHCP relay, which I don't know how to configure; pfSense has separate `DHCP relay` service, which I have stopped. Inside `DHCP server` I can't find relay options.

Answer (score 2):

You were getting that IP address because you had the DHCP relay service activated.

The "DHCP relay" functionality that is present in many brands of firewalls and routers, is a functionality to propagate in a router the DHCP requests for a DHCP server that is on another network e.g. to be able to use only a DHCP server for several networks - but then the DHCP server has to be configured and aware that are several networks - while the one at router3 only gives IP addresses of one and only network.

Has you find out, disabling the DHCP relay functionality in pfSense, you won't get more on that position of the network an address of 192.168.100.0/24

Comment: So, how to disable DHCP relay in pfSense?

Comment: @Dims I though you said you stopped it; if that is the case, I can tell you later on. In my mobile now.

Comment: I stopped it, yes, but DHCP in another subnet is still reacheable.

Comment: for that to happen without DHCP relay, AP1 has to be connected to the 192.168.100.5 interface and not to 192.168.10.1. The AP could not care less about it´s own IP, it is just for administration (normally it is a bridge). Unless it doing routing, and you redefined in the wifi interface 192.168.100.0/24 again by mistake.

Comment: So, you just don't beleive that things happen as I describe. Okay.

Comment: `AP1` is transparent. Imagine, that notebook is connected directly to `LAN`

Comment: I havent said I do not believe it. mistakes happen, or otherwise pfsense is doing bridging

Comment: You were generally right thinking that there is unknown factor -- looks like I found it.

Comment: @Dims So what is it?

Comment: See my update please, it was separate DHCP device!

Comment: @Dims makes sense... I was suspecting of something similar. please do keep the relay off, you had those two probs.